# Python aiohttp - Sending gzipped Response Taking Very Long

Tags: python, gzip, aiohttp

I have built a fairly simple API in Python 3.5 using the aiohttp framework.  In evaluating performance, I have discovered that sending the response data seems to be the bottleneck.  When looking at the Network tab in Chrome Developer tools, the average Waiting (TTFB) for calls to this api may be something like 1 second.  The Content Download component is something like 4-5 seconds.  The gzipped content is in the range of 5-10 MB.

The api and client are not on the same server - but are both in the same sand-boxed environment.  So I don't think network latency is the cause.  I am doing 20MB .zip file downloads served from apache almost instantaneously...

Below is a utility function that gzips any json-like object for streaming to the client.  Is there a better way to do this?

```
def gzipped_json_response(obj):
    obj_as_bytes = bytes(json.dumps(obj), 'utf-8')
    out = gzip.compress(obj_as_bytes, compresslevel=5)
    return aiohttp.web.Response(
        body=out,
        headers={
            "Content-Encoding":"gzip"
        }
    )
```

Comment: Timing each call in your function may be a good starting point to see which call is causing issues.

Answer (score 0):

1. You can compress response with nginx, which should be faster
2. If you serve static file you can use FileResponse, which uses "sendfile" os api.